# JMeter 3.2 Point-to-Point configuration for IBM MQ 8 => Java Exception

Tags: java, jmeter, ibm-mq

I am trying to use JMeter Point-to-Point JNDI configuration for IBM MQ 8 and receive the error message below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: QueueConnectionFactory expected, but got com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory
```

**Configuration:**

1. Configure JNDI context in MQExplorer
2. Testplan with additional com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar
3. JMS Point-to-Point Sampler with JNDI Configuration

=> Result with exception Response message

[JMS Point-to-Point Sampler with JNDI Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sanB9.jpg)

[Result with exception Response message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNKep.jpg)

I also tried to copy the required jar file (com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar) to the JMeter lib directory. Unfortunately without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a MQQueueConnectionFactory in MQExplorer instead of the MQConnectionFactory you have now.